# Check if a directory contains another directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How do I check if a given directory contains another directory in shell. I want to pass 2 full path directories. (I know this is stupid, but just for learning purposes). Then I want to see if any one of those 2 paths is contained in the other one.

```
parent=$1
child=$2

if [ -d $child ]; then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

this however makes no use of the parent directory. Only checks if the child exists.

Comment: You want to see if `$parent` is a parent of `$child` at some level? That's a string prefix check (assuming you aren't worried about symlinks, `../` games, etc.).

Comment: Use `find -type d -name "$child"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `find` to see if one name is contained within another:

```
result=$(find "$parent" -type d -name "$child")
if [[ -n $result ]]
then echo YES
else echo NO
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28335557/315024) but far more reliable than name comparisons:

```sh
if find "$parent" -samefile "$child" -printf 'Y\n' -quit | grep -qF Y; then
    echo "contains '$child'"
fi
```

To be even safer, you can also follow symlinks to ensure that there's no way a recursive operation on `$parent` could damage `$child` or anything in it:

```sh
if find -L "$parent" -samefile "$child" -printf 'Y\n' -quit | grep -qF Y; then
    echo "contains '$child' or link thereto"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file (ex: `dircontains.sh`) with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function dircontains_syntax {
    local msg=$1
    echo "${msg}" >&2
    echo "syntax: dircontains <parent> <file>" >&2
    return 1
}

function dircontains {
    local result=1
    local parent=""
    local parent_pwd=""
    local child=""
    local child_dir=""
    local child_pwd=""
    local curdir="$(pwd)"
    local v_aux=""

    # parameters checking
    if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
        dircontains_syntax "exactly 2 parameters required"
        return 2
    fi
    parent="${1}"
    child="${2}"

    # exchange to absolute path
    parent="$(readlink -f "${parent}")"
    child="$(readlink -f "${child}")"
    dir_child="${child}"

    # direcory checking
    if [ ! -d "${parent}" ];  then
        dircontains_syntax "parent dir ${parent} not a directory or doesn't exist"
        return 2
    elif [ ! -e "${child}" ];  then
        dircontains_syntax "file ${child} not found"
        return 2
    elif [ ! -d "${child}" ];  then
        dir_child=`dirname "${child}"`
    fi

    # get directories from $(pwd)
    cd "${parent}"
    parent_pwd="$(pwd)"
    cd "${curdir}"  # to avoid errors due relative paths
    cd "${dir_child}"
    child_pwd="$(pwd)"

    # checking if is parent
    [ "${child_pwd:0:${#parent_pwd}}" = "${parent_pwd}" ] && result=0

    # return to current directory
    cd "${curdir}"
    return $result
}
```

Then run these commands

```
. dircontains.sh

dircontains path/to/dir/parent any/file/to/test

# the result is in $? var 
# $1=0, <file> is in <dir_parent>
# $1=1, <file> is not in <dir_parent>
# $1=2, error
```

Obs:
- Tested only in ubuntu 16.04/bash
- In this case, the second parameter can be any Linux file

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash, no external commands used:

```
#!/bin/bash

parent=$1
child=$2
[[ $child && $parent ]] || exit 2 # both arguments must be present
child_dir="${child%/*}"           # get the dirname of child
if [[ $child_dir = $parent && -d $child ]]; then
  echo YES
else
  echo NO
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for sub-directories too:

```
parent=$1
child=$2

if [[ ${child/$parent/} != $child ]] ; then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this in pure bash. Loop over every file in $1 and see if "$1/$2" is a dir, like so:

```
parent=$1
child=$(basename $2)
if [ -d $parent ] && [ -d $child ]; then
    for child in $parent; do
        if [ -d "$parent/$child" ]; then
            echo "Yes"
        else
            echo "No"
        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: The reason why this won't work is because in the second if stattement, you are appending the entire child path to the parent path. This results in a non-existent directory and it will always result in NO.

Comment: @Kanny Bros, use `child=$(basename $2)` if you'd only like the folder name of `$child` instead of its absolute path.